# silverstripe set default HTMLText value

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I need to set a default value for a HTMLEditorField so the user can use that as a starting point when adding content.

**I have tried to set the default value in populateDefaults in different ways without any success. Is it not possible to set default values for HTMLText?**

The code bellow displays what I'm trying to do.

```
  private static $db = [
      'MyHtmlField' => 'HTMLText'
   ];

   public function getCMSFields()
   {
      $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
      $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HTMLEditorField::create('MyHtmlField'), 'Content');
      return $fields;
   }

   public function populateDefaults()
   {
      $this->MyHtmlField =
         DBHTMLText::create('<p>Some content</p>'
   );
```

Comment: I'd suspect that you are missing the parent::populateDefaults() call after setting the value. See: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/how_tos/dynamic_default_fields/.  Also why not just set the value with $this->MyHtmlField = "blaah".. can't figure out a reason to use that DBHTML::create at all..

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a default value when a page is first created?

```
# File: Page.php
public function onBeforeWrite()
{
    parent::onBeforeWrite();

    if (!$this->isInDB()) {
        // Set some default content
        $this->MyHtmlField = '<p>Some content</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function for `populateDefaults` does not need `DBHTMLText::create` and make a call to the super class afterwards.. please see the [docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/how_tos/dynamic_default_fields/):

```
public function populateDefaults() {

      $this->MyHtmlField = '<p>Some content</p>';

      parent::populateDefaults();
}
```